# Abstract class from a concrete class in Python

Tags: python, abstract-class, pathlib

With the release of Python 3.12, `pathlib.Path` can now be subclassed. I want to create a subclass `CustomPath(Path)` for non-`os` environments (ftp, sftp, s3 storage, etc.), meaning I have to re-implemented (almost) all methods.

I want to make sure that `CustomPath`is only using methods which are defined in the subclass, to prevent accidentally using methods from the parent `Path` class. In order to do this, I want to use only the interface (abstract class) of `Path`. (Since `Path` may be updated to include new methods beyond my control.)

What is the most pythonic way of doing this? (It might be the case that it is not appropriate to subclass at all.)

---

Here's an example of expected behavior:

```py
class S3Path(pathlib.Path):
    @classmethod
    def from_connection(cls, ...):
        ...  # custom implementation

    def read_text(self, encoding=None, errors=None):
        ...  # custom implementation


s3path = S3Path.from_connection(...)

text = s3path.read_text()
s3path.write_text(text)  # should raise NotImplementedError
```

Comment: i have rarely if ever used class methods (generally try to avoid decorators), but this seems like the correct use case.

Comment: @D.L The question is not about class methods. Class methods are common for constructors since Python lacks function overloading. You can find many [examples in the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/genindex-F.html) (under "from").

Comment: Just override `write_text` to raise `NotImplementedError`. "Concrete" isn't contrasting with abstract classes, but with `PurePath` (which represents path objects that can't do I/O).

Comment: Why do you feel inclined to subclass `pathlib.Path` at *all*? We're not in Java; Python is duck-typed, so anything that vaguely looks like a path counts as one. If you want static type-checking, just use [protocols](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/) and you *still* don't need a subclass. Python subclassing is *only* for the implementation, since we don't have Java-style interfaces.

Comment: @chepner it's to be forward-compatible: If a new method is included in a future version of `pathlib.Path`, I want to make sure that my subclass raises `NotImplementedError` if I forget to implement it.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I might end up not using inheritance, but there are cases where subclassing might be useful in case `issubclass` or `isinstance` is used, so I think it could still be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am the current pathlib maintainer. I'm looking to add pathlib ABCs in future, and in fact they already exist (privately) in CPython. For the time being you may wish to use the "pathlib-abc" PyPI package, which is a straight copy-paste of the private functionality.

Comment: Thanks for maintaining this! `pathlib-abc` is exactly what I need, so hopefully it will be included in the future :)

Answer (score 2):

I can see two options:

**OPTION 1**: override parent methods you want to 'hide' by providing an empty body like here:

```
class MyPath(pathlib.Path):
    def is_dir(self):
        pass
```

**OPTION 2**: Since you don't want to use any methods of the base class I suggest using plain class instead of inheritance. It'll prevent you from using parent class methods accidentally. Just implement the methods you need according to the pathlib.Path specification and your requirements.

Here's an example of how you can implement this:

```
import pathlib

class MyPath:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self._path = path

    def exists(self):
        return r'custom implementation of 'exists''

    ######## any other methods

# Example usage:
my_path = MyPath('/path/to/file')
print(my_path.exists())
```